# Caps lock won't turn off automatically in Office 365 after running a particular program

Tags: windows-7, capslock, microsoft-office-2016

I am experiencing an issue with **SBClient**, which is an IBM Telnet client, interacting with Office 365 2016.

I upgraded a user to Office 365 2016.  Before they run **SBClient**, when they use spell check in Office and have caps lock on, it will auto-correct a word and turn caps lock off. For example,

> mANAGEMENT

will become

> Management

and turn caps lock off.

This feature stops working once the **SBClient** has been run. Only a restart seems to restore the feature.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?